# How to get Images from JSON to main.xml file

Tags: android, json, list

I am not getting images from JSON.

How to get "LogoFileName" image from my JSON. I am only getting the title and description. But i need LogoFileName also.
If any body knows any solutions please help me.

**Code:**

```
{"Channels":[{"AlertDetailsFont":"","AlertDetailsFontId":0,"AlertHeaderFont":"","AlertHeaderFontId":0,"Category":"Education","CategoryId":7,"ChannelId":53,"Color1":"Red","Color2":"Black","Color3":"Black","Color4":"","Color5":"","ColorCode1":"FF0000","ColorCode2":"000000","ColorCode3":"000000","ColorCode4":"","ColorCode5":"","ColorId1":1,"ColorId2":3,"ColorId3":3,"ColorId4":0,"ColorId5":0,"Description":"This must be visible now","FontSize":"12px","FontSizeId":1,"HeaderFont":"Arial","HeaderFontId":2,"IsBold":false,"IsItalic":false,"LogoFileName":"http:\/\/183.82.97.146:1111\/CAWebsite\/UserImages\/ChannelLogos\/02022012_170628.jpg","ModifiedBy":12,"ModifiedDate":"\/Date(1328182588000+0530)\/","ModifiedUsername":"skrt","PublicChannelId":"f12d79aa-4267-11e1-a94b-0021706baaba","TickerFont":"","TickerFontId":0,"Title":"Books"},,.................etc
```

Hi here is my code..

## main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://my path...");


   try{

        JSONArray  channels = json.getJSONArray("Channels");

        for(int i=0;i<channels.length();i++){                       
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String> ();   
        JSONObject e = channels.getJSONObject(i);

        map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("name", e.getString("Title"));
            map.put("Category", e.getString("Category"));
            //map.put("imageUrl", e.getString("LogoFileName"));

            imageUrl= e.getString("LogoFileName");

            System.out.println("Logo Url:"+imageUrl);

            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
               }catch(JSONException e)        
              {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
              }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "Category" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: you do not see the `System.out.println("Logo Url:"+imageUrl)` output, right? Use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: I am getting like this in LogCat..                                     02-21 15:17:40.657: INFO/System.out(1023): Logo Url:http://183.82.97.146:1111/CAWebsite/UserImages/ChannelLogos/02192012_194308.jpg
02-21 15:17:40.657: INFO/System.out(1023): Logo Url:http://183.82.97.146:1111/CAWebsite/UserImages/ChannelLogos/02172012_192918.jpg
02-21 15:17:40.667: INFO/System.out(1023): Logo Url:http://183.82.97.146:1111/CAWebsite/UserImages/ChannelLogos/02192012_195102.jpg

Comment: I am getting like this in LogCat..                                     02-21 15:17:40.657: INFO/System.out(1023): Logo Url:http://xxx..xxx:xxxx/CAWebsite/UserImages/ChannelLogos/02192012_194308.jpg

Comment: hi.. here is my out put link.. please find it. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/device-2012-02-21-160344.png

Comment: OK, you do get the image URL from your JSON, and I guess your question should have been formulated as "How to load image into ImageView from URL?". Am I right?

Comment: ok Thank You.. I am  new to android, i don't know how to get image URL from my JSON. did u know any link for that..b

Comment: ok.. Thank You..I am using bellow code.. is it fine..?but i didn't get any images..? Here is my code..

Comment: private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String   saveFilename) {
 try {
InputStream is = (InputStream)                             this.fetch(url);
 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
 System.out.println("images:"+d);
       
    return;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
       return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
     }
     }
public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
URL url = new URL(address);
Object content = url.getContent();
return content;
}

Comment: I am  new to android, i don't know how to get image URL from my JSON. did u know any link for that..Thank you..